# Has anyone managed to successfully pass parameters to SSIS via a Data Factory ExecuteSSISPackage task?

Tags: parameters, ssis-2012, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass parameters to SSIS via a Data Factory ExecuteSSISPackage task.

I have added project parameters, package parameters etc to the JSON code but they are always null in SSIS.  An excerpt of the JSON code is shown below.

```
"packageParameters ": {
     "X": { "value": "@pipeline().parameters.X"},
     "Y": { "value : "xyzzy"  }}
```

If you have successfully passed parameters can you give me some hints or direct me to documentation.  It has been difficult so far to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove the blank space within "packageParameters " and try again? I have tried it, and it works fine to me.

Comment: Sorry, the space was added when I was the typing the question.  The original code does not have a space.  Is your "packageParameters" object within the "typeProperties" object?

Comment: Yes, "packageParameters" is an field of "typeProperties". Could you confirm parameters in package and json have the same name? If it still not work, could you provide more detail about your parameter and json?